# Prevent automatic redirect and get redirect URL of PassportJs "authenticate" method

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm trying to encapsulate [Passport.js](http://www.passportjs.org/) strategies inside adapters, such as `FacebookProviderAdapter`, `TwitchProviderAdapter`, and so on... and for that, I need to "prevent" the default behavior of passport that automatically redirects the browser to the social network's OAuth URL

just to give more context, my abstract adapter it's something like this:

```
interface SocialAuthProviderInterface {
  generateRedirectUrl(): string;
}
```

I'm not using sessions, and I was able to use the callback "version" of the Passport.Js, but even tho it still redirects and I can't intercept the redirect URL string.

I realized that Passport is also tightly coupled to the Express.js library and sets everything inside its code, the documentation is very superficial to these aspects, how can I prevent the URL redirect and get the plain redirect URL out of any strategy?

my current test setup is the following:

`/login/google` is the starting endpoint that generates the oauth URL to google, this is the redirect that I want to prevent, I would like to have just the plain URL string.

```
app.get('/login/google', (request, response) => {
  passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile email'], session: false}, (err, user, info) => {
    console.log(err, user, info)
  })(request, response)
})

app.get('/google', (request, response) => {
  passport.authenticate('google', { session: false }, (err, user, info) => {
    console.log(err, user, info)
  })(request);
})
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend create a new `ServerResponse` instance.

```js
const passport = require('passport')
const { ServerResponse } = require('http')

app.get('/login/google', (request, response) => {
  const emptyResponse = new ServerResponse(request)

  passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile email'], session: false}, (err, user, info) => {
    console.log(err, user, info)
  })(request, emptyResponse)

  console.log(emptyResponse.getHeader('location'))
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone's is stuck with this problem, here's how I solved it:

**for the URL redirect:**

since passport js is highly coupled to the Express JS lib, inside the `passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:315` you can see where it's defined the redirect function with Express js, the key part is the `res.end()`, where I manually replaced with a function to return the value of `url`

```
authenticate.js
```

[image]

```
my workaround
```

[image]

it's not pretty but it works :)

Comment: This gave me an error: `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`